# Angular JS JSON2CSV

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

While I am trying to download filter data in ng-table to CSV, I am getting the single row split into two rows.

**Output will be like below**

**Row1** contains three columns

```
Item 1 | 12222-12228-14567-124568-18680-20940-18717-ABCDED-sdf_dsfsdf | X-Large
```

Instead am getting

**1st row**

```
Item 1 | 12222-12228-14567-124568-18680-20940-18717-ABCDED-sdf_dsfsdf |
```

**2nd row**

```
X-Large
```

here is my code

```
var data = [{ "name": "Item 1", "color": "12222-12228-14567-124568-18680-20940-18717-ABCDED-aSFDasdf_sdfsdf_dsfsdf", "size": "X-Large" },
     { "name": "Item 2", "color": "Green", "size": "X-Large" },
     { "name": "Item 3", "color": "Green", "size": "X-Large" }];

$scope.downloadData = function (data){
       var csv = $scope.JsonToCsv(data);         
}

$scope.JsonToCsv = function(objArray) {
var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) :objArray;
        var str = '';
        var line = '';
        var head = array[0];
        for (var index in array[0]) {
            var value = index + "";
            line += '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '",';
        }
        line = line.slice(0, -1);
        str += line + '\r\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                line += array[i][index] + ',';
            }
            line = line.slice(0, -1);
            str += line + '\r\n';
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Can anyone help me by finding what went wrong in my code?

Comment: I have just run this code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x74y0fjs/) and it seems to work. It might be worth providing a bit more code for example how that function get called in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working code for this , I changed as per your need. Hopes this works for you too

```
            var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
            var str = '';
            var line = "";
            for (var index in array[0]) {
                line += index + ',';
            }
            line = line.slice(0, -1);
            str += line + '\r\n';
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var line = "";
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    line += '"' + array[i][index] + '",';
                }
                line.slice(0, line.length - 1);
                str += line + '\r\n';
            }
            if (str == '') {
                alert("oops");
                return;
            }
            console.log(str);
            return str;
```

Thanks :)